# using jquery to return multiple values for my registration form validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

hi i am trying to carry out dynamic checks on my registration form, so when the user enters information, the php code is checking it for errors.currently, i am only trying to pass the values back to jquery to be displayed on the form, i have not yet carried out any validation on the input boxes. i can only seem to pass one value back, as soon as i try and pass multiple values, nothing gets returned, any help would be mostly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should send the whole form if you want to validate multiple inputs at once to your php.

Your validate function should look something like

```
function validate(fname, lname){
$.post('php/registration.php', $("form").serialize(), function(data){
        $('#fname_feedback').text(data.fname);
        $('#lname_feedback').text(data.lname);
    },'json');
}}
```

And your php function could be something like (until you do the validation)

```
$return_data=$_POST;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_data);
exit();
```

}

Comment: do i need to put my input boxes in form tags and give it an id or form

Comment: I would recommend every time you use inputs to have them into a form. If you have many forms, then add an id to it, if not you can just use it as $("form"). 
They might be other ways to achieve want you want, but I believe this is the tidiest.

Comment: thanks I have changed my code like you said and it does not work.

Comment: can you add a console.log(data) on the validate function to see what the php is returning? I've used the serialize many times. Also, can you please post how the HTML is now with the form tag? Sorry, but also, the validation for blank inputs is not necessary and no parameters should be sent to the validation function

Comment: do you see the XHR call to registration.php on dev tools / firebug? Try seeing what you're sending as form to that request and seeing what you get as return, and you'll probably see the problem there. If you want, paste it and i'll look at it

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: That's a php error on your controller. I'm pretty sure if you can solve that it will be fix (not the whole php file is on the code you send I believe)

Comment: That was all my php code that I used, in my above post